# Как правильно делегировать события в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить проблему с добавлением события при нажатии на элемент который создается в цикле. Как правильно это сделать?

```
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('message');
    });

    for(let users in data[i]) {
        if (users !== 'company' && users !== 'address' ){
            let td = document.createElement('td');

            td.innerHTML = data[i][users];
            tr.append(td);
        }
        table.append(tr);
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Ну напишите, в чём проблема?))

Comment: Разве что эффективней может быть использование https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation с привязкой к table.

Comment: Вроде все норм. Поддерживаю @vsemozhebuty

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, эффективность может зависеть от конкретной разметки

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае будет эффективней использовать делегирование событий. Идея в том, что если у нас есть много элементов, события на которых обрабатываются одинаково, то вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик каждому, мы можем использовать один обработчик для их общего предка. Реализуется это примерно так:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table').onclick = (e) => {
  const target = e.target // Где был клик?

  if (target.tagName !== 'TD') return // Не на TD? Тогда останавливаем скрипт.

  console.log('Клик был на ' + target) // Показываем TD, на который кликнули.
}
```

Этот способ экономит память, так как не нужно вешать множество обработчиков.